# xsl: concat two variables into new one

Tags: xslt

I'm just learning xsl. I am trying to concatenate the value of two variables and put a hyphen between them. This is my code:

```
<xsl:variable name="checkboxvalue" select="translate(@value, ' ', '')" />
                            <xsl:variable name="questionname" select="{ancestor::element/attribute::name}"/>
            <xsl:variable name="newcheckboxvalue" select="concat($questionname,-,$checkboxvalue)"/>
```

When I run the page that uses this .xsl file I get that 
 Unexpected token \"{\" in path expression","Fatal Error: Unexpected token \",\" in path expression

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is due to the second variable

```
<xsl:variable name="questionname" select="{ancestor::element/attribute::name}"/>
```

It is not allowed to use curly braces here, as XSLT already expects an expression in the `select` attribute. You should just do this.

```
 <xsl:variable name="questionname" select="ancestor::element/attribute::name" />
```

Or this...

```
<xsl:variable name="questionname" select="ancestor::element/@name" />
```

Also, for your third statement, you need to wrap the hyphen in apostrophes, to treat it is a string

```
 <xsl:variable name="newcheckboxvalue" select="concat($questionname, '-' ,$checkboxvalue)"/>
```

If you want to learn about the use of curly braces, read up on [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: Thank you for the help and the link!